# Packing an Actionscript (Flash Builder) application for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, flash, flash-builder

Recently I tried to build a flash application in Flash Builder, and I wanted to export it to my iPhone. I have gone through all the required steps in order to certify my application.
Now, with all that done, all that was left to be done is building the ".ipa" file in Flash Builder. Now, this gives the following error:

> 'Launching TestGame' has encountered a problem.
>
> Error occurred while packaging the application:
>
> NotBefore: Wed Apr 11 18:52:40 CEST 2012

Google didn't give me a decent answer, nor does Adobe's information regarding mobile application development. All I can think off, is that I can't build the application before that date. That's ridiculous, I can't imagine a certain check like that.

I'm pretty sure my ".p12" key file is generated correctly.
Is anyone else familiar with this error? Please, be so kind to guide me in the right direction.

Kind regards,

Matthias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest compiling from command line. I'd ported an AIR app to iOS and compiled using `adt` dirrectly (without FB or whatever), and there were more meanful messages then yours. Take a look at the [manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac35eb7b4e12cddc5fbbb-8000.html) on how to build `ipa` wit `adt`. The other advise is to check your `iPhone` node in `app.xml` (take a look [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-8000.html#WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-7fd6)) and [icons](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d129907d2886-8000.html).

Answer (score 3):

The error occurs because the compiler didn't find the files under the corresponding directory such as debug-bin or release-bin folder. (explains from: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/893772)

For example, if you are doing a debug-build, and you didn't select the project option: copy non-embeded files to the output folder.  And debug-build needs some files such as icons files under the debug-bin folder, and it couldn't find it.

Solution: select project compiling option: the copy non-embeded file to the output folder. 
Try again, if still not you will need to try the ADT build to get more details http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac35eb7b4e12cddc5fbbb-8000.html

Answer (score 1):

The "error" was thrown because the certificate wasn't valid yet. It became valid on the date shown above.

You could also fix the manifest file in the iOS developers center.

Answer (score 0):

This problem does come up more often than needed. The error reporting is lacking distinctions but is also difficult to asses since there can be many factors causing this error. If it was one factor or even just a few then it would most likely let you know.

A great way to ensure that the error reporting can do its job and tell you where the problem is is to check your error log. It will tell you at least a few of the places that threw the block.

If you are unable to read those strange glyphs then just ensure that all your resources are being packaged. This does mean a little time of list checking but it is well worth it, for the  errors and to get rid of development junk.

The first step in the asset list check is to go through each part of your Assets class (flash builder reference). If you do not have a direct Assets class then you may want to make one and move all of your asset calls to that one class - since it will save you time if this happens again.

Your Assets class is not the same as your Assets folder. Your folder is where the files are stored - i.e. images, bitmaps, sounds, etc. Your Assets class is what categorizes and assigns references to each individual file.

Go through your Assets class to ensure that each of those files exist in the folder as well. Then go to the Project menu (top near Navigate and Search) and select Clean. Either clean all your projects or check the current one. Once this is done you need to click on your Assets Folder (right click or highlight and hit edit or whatever), and select Refresh. This will check that all the files are still there and get rid of/update them.

If none of this throws an error -red X- or other errors then you need to check your project .xml file. This may take you some time to ensure that all of your add on packages and details are correct. Make sure you have the correct:


at the top and it matches your current air release.
Make sure all the filenames, names, ids, version numbers, aspect ratios, fullscreen, visible, icons, extensionIDs, and everything else are not only correct but actually there. Most of these statements should have something written and not be blank. If they are blank find out what to put in.

Ensure that you have the proper icon file extension. If it says assets/icon48.png and the icon48.png is actually in assets/pictures/images/icons/toomanyfilesextensions/whatever/icon48.png
you need to fix that link.

The last thing that you will need to check is when you want to either Release Build or Debug. You need to make sure that all assets are checked and selected.
Go to Project - Properties.
then select ActionScript Build Path.
Click the Native Extensions tab and see if there are any red X's. If there are tap the little arrow beside them and see what the matter it. Add the correct ANE or get rid of it or whatever you need to do. 
Then in the same menu go to the left and select ActionScript Build Packaging. A little arrow should be beside that one too. Tap the arrow and it will open to Apple iOS, BlackBerry, Gooogle and whatever else you have (probably nothing more). Select the OS your want to use, lets say Apple, and you will have 4 tabs pop up. Make sure you have the correct certificates selected. If you have none or are confused about this you need to spend some time on Google.

The biggest one for this error is under the Package Contents tab. Most people miss this!
Open the tab and see if anything is not checked. There will 99.99% be something or many of them not checked if you are getting this error. Just check them all and you can figure out what you need and don't need later. Some of them will be listed because you just threw in a bunch of ANEs and .SWFs to have some awesome app. Those add on packages will throw in unnecessary contents into this package. That is fine and don't worry until you want to be picky. Just make sure they are all selected and hit Apply and Ok.

That's it. You should have a working Release Build if you did everything else correct and this error should be easy from now on (but time wasting).

You may get a 'slip' error now, but that is another story. But that is a great sign because you are getting closer to that stupid mistake that we all make: the elusive spelling mistake.